# Mist wallet change from private-net to test-net

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I downloaded the mist wallet for ethereum and when i open up the program it sometimes connects me automatically to the private-net instead of the test-net. In this case i don't know how to change back the mist wallet to connect to the test-net. When i am in the private-net if i go to the tab  develop>network the choices of main network, testnet (morden) are grey and i can't press them. same goes for the Geth and Eth option under tab develop>ethereum node. i tried pressing ctrl+shift+2 but nothing happens. Anyone knows how to change to the testnet instead of privatenet?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Mist interface is confusing sometimes and it does not allow you to switch the network of a running node.

But you can get back control if you run your geth node before you run Mist.

For private network: `geth --dev`

For public testnet: `geth --testnet`

Mist will automatically detect the running geth instance and connect to the `geth.ipc` socket. Hope this helps.